# D3 force layout - Links exceed the boundaries of the container, while dragging the nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I created a d3-force layout. The nodes are allowed to be dragged within a boundary box only. When the nodes are close to the boundaries, the nodes stay fixed at their positions, according to the following functions:

```
function boundX(x) {
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(width - (nodeWidth+padding), x));
}

function boundY(y){
    return Math.max(0, Math.min(height - (nodeHeight+padding), y))
}
```

The nodes are connected via polylines. Each polyline is characterized by two segments. The first segment is defined by the source node's (`d.source.x+nodeWidth/2, d.source.y+nodeHeight/2`) coordinates, which is the middle of the node and the intersection point of the line with the target node. The second segment starts at the intersection point with the target node and ends at the target nodes middle point(`d.target.x+nodeWidth/2`).The intersection of a line and a target node is where a marker is placed along the polyline. This is the part of the code -in the tick function- which is responsible for calculating the intersection points, and drawing the lines:

```
    function tick() {

    link.attr("points", function(d) {

        var interForw = pointOnRect(d.source.x, d.source.y,
            d.target.x - nodeWidth / 2, d.target.y - nodeHeight / 2,
            d.target.x + nodeWidth / 2, d.target.y + nodeHeight / 2);

        if(d.direction==="forward") {
        return boundXInter((d.source.x+nodeWidth/2) + " "
            + boundYInter(((d.source.y) + nodeHeight / 2) + ","
            + boundXInter(((interForw.x+nodeWidth/2))) + " "
            + boundYInter((interForw.y) + nodeHeight / 2) + ","
            + boundXInter(d.target.x+nodeWidth/2) + " "
            + boundYInter((d.target.y) + nodeHeight / 2);
}
```

These are the functions for defining the boundaries for the links:

```
    function boundXInter(x) {
    return Math.max(nodeWidth/2, Math.min(width - (nodeWidth/2+padding),x));
}
function boundYInter(y){
    return Math.max(nodeHeight/2, Math.min(height - (nodeHeight/2+padding), y));
}
```

When two nodes are one below the other like in the first image. It behaves as expected. [image].

However, when the nodes are placed as shown in the next figure, if the user continues dragging the nodes even if they not allowed to move further the boundaries, the nodes are blocked as wanted, but the links continue to move until the `width-nodeWidth/2` point, according to the `boundXInter` function.

[image]

What I would like to achieve is the intersection point (the marker), the first segment of the line not to move further than it's actual position in this case as shown in the third figure. I want it to be fixed and not that segment of the line stretch to the `width-nodeWidth/2` position as shown in the next figure. Probably, reformating the boundXInter function would do the job. But, I have tried many combinations  and it did not. I would like to mention that if the user stops dragging the links return to the desired state (as shown in the second Figure)

[image]

Any ideas? What can I do, in this case, to get the correct result?

You can find a working snippet here: https://jsfiddle.net/yx2grm4s/39/.

Comment: Could you please create a snippet (JsBin, Fiddle or something)?  it's easier to help

Comment: Are you drawing everything relative to the top left coordinate of the nodes? It is a lot easier to draw the box centered around the node-XY location so the lines start and stop at the node-XY, no need to calculate the w*.5,h*.5 offset, the nodes can be drawn with negative `x` and `y` attributes if you use transforms on a `g` element.

Comment: @V.Sambor: I just added a snippet in the main body of the question

Comment: The snippet does not work for me. it does not allow me to drag anything and the initial draw look strange.

Comment: Should be working now! @rioV8

Comment: @rioV8 Does the snippet work? https://jsfiddle.net/yx2grm4s/36/

Comment: You have to select part of the node that is not the text. Now the start looks better.

Comment: Updated snippet https://jsfiddle.net/yx2grm4s/39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed modelling relative to the center and relative to the top left of the rectangle. It is nicer to do it relative to the center (is the **node** position). Do not change the node position other then bounds check. The rectangle, label, link and dot are just decoration relative to the node position.

Also bound node position first before updating the "in between node" stuff so that will **never** need to be bound again. Use a nice even padding all around the box.

Removed code duplication.

Complete running code: https://jsfiddle.net/y0eox2vn/1/

Essential code part

```
var link = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    // .append("line")
    .append("polyline")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .style("stroke-width","1")
    .style("stroke","black")
    .style("fill","none")
    .attr("id", function (d, i) { return 'link'+i; });

var markerFor = svg.append("defs")
    .selectAll("marker")
    .data(["forward"])
    .enter()
    .append("marker")
    .attr("id", "dirArrowFor")
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("markerUnits", "strokeWidth")
    .attr("markerWidth", 10)
    .attr("markerHeight", 10)
    .attr("refX",10)
    .attr("refY", 0)
    .attr("overflow", "visible")
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5")
    .style("fill", "#000000");

    link.attr("marker-mid", checkDir);

 var linkNode = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class","link-node")
    .attr("r",4)
    .style("fill","#c00");

linkNode.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.linkingWord; });

 var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class","node")
    .attr("width", conceptWidth)
    .attr("height", conceptHeight)
    .attr("rx",20)
    .attr("ry",20)
    .style('fill',function(d){ return d.color;})
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragStarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragEnded));

var labels = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".labels")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .text(function(d){ return d.name;})
    .style("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr("dy", 5);

var force = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("collision", d3.forceCollide(conceptWidthHalf +1).iterations(1))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d){ return d.name;}))
    .on("tick", tick);

force.nodes(nodes);
force.force("link").links(links);

function interForwRev(d) {
    var interForw = pointOnRect(d.source.x, d.source.y,
        d.target.x - conceptWidthHalf, d.target.y - conceptHeightHalf,
        d.target.x + conceptWidthHalf, d.target.y + conceptHeightHalf);

    var interRev = pointOnRect(d.target.x, d.target.y,
        d.source.x - conceptWidthHalf, d.source.y - conceptHeightHalf ,
        d.source.x + conceptWidthHalf, d.source.y + conceptHeightHalf);
    return [interForw, interRev];
}

function tick() {

    node.attr("x", function(d) { d.x=boundX(d.x); return d.x - conceptWidthHalf;  })
        .attr("y", function(d) { d.y=boundY(d.y); return d.y - conceptHeightHalf; });

    labels.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x;  })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; });

    linkNode.attr("cx", function (d) {
        var interFR = interForwRev(d);
        var interForw = interFR[0];
        var interRev  = interFR[1];

        return d.cx = (interForw.x + interRev.x)*0.5;
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
        var interFR = interForwRev(d);
        var interForw = interFR[0];
        var interRev  = interFR[1];

        return d.cy = (interForw.y + interRev.y)*0.5;
    });

    // update the links after the nodes so we are already bounded by the box
    link.attr("points", function(d) {
        var interFR = interForwRev(d);
        var interForw = interFR[0];
        var interRev  = interFR[1];

        if(d.direction==="forward") {
            return `${d.source.x} ${d.source.y},${interForw.x} ${interForw.y},${d.target.x} ${d.target.y}`;
        }
    });
}

function boundX(x) {
    return Math.max(conceptWidthHalf+padding, Math.min(width - (conceptWidthHalf+padding), x));
}

function boundY(y){
    return Math.max(conceptHeightHalf+padding, Math.min(height - (conceptHeightHalf+padding), y))
}

// NO other bound function needed

function dragStarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) force.alphaTarget(0.03).restart();

    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Mainly, the problem derived from the fact that I did not bound the nodes first.